# Google Groups Audit Email

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

is it possible to audit google groups mails?

I would like to know when the last time someone write to a google group.

Email Log Search is nice but i cant find this in any Google API. Or something like Account Activity for Google Groups.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to tracking of changes to groups, group memberships and group messages within your domain and troubleshoot when users within your domain notice discrepancies and unexpected changes to their groups activities, please check further in [Groups audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6270454?hl=en).

Please note, however, that groups audit log is only for the Google Groups interface and it logs both user and admin actions executed using the interface. As stated further in Groups audit log, Google Groups actions performed by administrators using the admin console or the Admin SDK directory API are logged in the Admin Console general logs.

Comment: First of all thanks. I did found this API too but i do not need information about groups change. I need information about the email conversation. Did get a group this week/month a email from outside. Something like a Groups email audit log:)